# What are the risks associated with granting sysadmin permission to NT Authority\SYSTEM?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

What are the risks associated with granting sysadmin permission to NT Authority\SYSTEM?  The Azure best practices analyzer for VM SQL appears to want this.

Answer (score 3):

The main risk is configuring services to run under SYSTEM.  Making SYSTEM a sysadmin adds on a negligible additional risk, as SYSTEM can do literally anything, including stopping SQL Server, restarting it in single user mode, adding sysadmins, restarting SQL Server and clearing the application and security logs.

So the relevant question is whether you trust the software you're running as SYSTEM.